# Need help redirect internet explorer user based on user agent string

Tags: javascript

I am using the following script with some minor changes to redirect the users based on their browsers and it works perfectly except users using internet explorer 11 are not being re-directed this is script

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browsern.htm

so i am looking to see what exactly i need to do to fix that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you doing this? Browser detection is generally a very bad idea because it is unreliable

Comment: What did you change?

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 lies about itself in its UA string to make itself look less like Internet Explorer.  It does that *precisely because* of scripts like this that try to serve IE users different content.  If you really want to catch IE 11, you should look for the word "Trident" in its UA string - but re-evaluate your approach because you really shouldn't be doing this in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: thanks for clarification, if i cannot redirect IE 11 users to specific page that would be fine  any possible way i can change to script to redirect chrome,firefox etc to some specific page and all other browsers with different string to one page? what change do i need to do achieve this ?

Comment: @Keshav Perhaps if you answer my question we can better help you. Instead you seem to have ignored it - why do you want to redirect browsers to a different page?

Comment: Is there something you are attempting to do that does not work in Edge?  If there is, then perhaps SO could help solve that problem rather than this.

Comment: You can redirect IE11, you just have to look for the right things in the UA string. Honestly though, IE11 is pretty reasonably standards compliant, so I'm not sure what your motivation is here.